# Moving rows between tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables (`campaigns` and `old_campaigns`) in a MySQL database.

Both tables have identical columns:  `id, user_id, url, ordered, sent, start_date, end_date`.

The columns `ordered` and `sent` are both integers.  Here's what I want to do:

I want to check to see if the number in the `sent` column is 1.25x higher than the number in the `ordered` column.  If it is, I want to move that row from that row from the `campaigns` to `old_campaigns` table.

For example, if `ordered` was 100, then if `sent` was 125+, that row should be moved.

I'm technically already doing this with PHP, I'm really just looking to see if there's a way to do this with pure MySQL and move all the rows at the same time, since my PHP script is currently having to loop through each row and check.

Comment: where ordered* 1.25 < sent

Comment: `INSERT INTO campaigns SELECT * from old_campaigns where sent>1.25*ordered`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420156/mysql-move-row-between-tables         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19821736/mysql-move-rows-from-one-table-to-another    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420156/mysql-move-row-between-tables